# "Reference path \"$.File_List.Payload\" must point to array

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

hi I have created a map state using step function and json of this look like this :

state machine json is :

```
{
  "StartAt": "files-metadata",
  "States": {
    "metadata-step": {
      "Next": "Map State",
      "Retry": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "Lambda.ServiceException",
            "Lambda.AWSLambdaException",
            "Lambda.SdkClientException"
          ],
          "IntervalSeconds": 2,
          "MaxAttempts": 6,
          "BackoffRate": 2
        }
      ],
      "Type": "Task",
      "OutputPath": "$",
      "ResultPath": "$.File_List",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke.waitForTaskToken",
      "Parameters": {
        "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:zzzzzz:function:files-metadata",
        "Payload": {
          "payload.$": "$",
          "taskToken.$": "$$.Task.Token"
        }
      }
    },
    "Map State": {
      "Type": "Map",
      "ResultPath": "$.Single.File",
      "Next": "check-file-processing-status",
      "Iterator": {
        "StartAt": "fetch-sample-data-step",
        "States": {
          "fetch-sample-data-step": {
            "End": true,
            "Retry": [
              {
                "ErrorEquals": [
                  "Lambda.ServiceException",
                  "Lambda.AWSLambdaException",
                  "Lambda.SdkClientException"
                ],
                "IntervalSeconds": 2,
                "MaxAttempts": 6,
                "BackoffRate": 2
              }
            ],
            "Type": "Task",
            "OutputPath": "$.Payload",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke.waitForTaskToken",
            "Parameters": {
              "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:zzzzzz:function:sample-data",
              "Payload": {
                "payload.$": "$",
                "taskToken.$": "$$.Task.Token"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "ItemsPath": "$.File_List.Payload",
      "MaxConcurrency": 1
    }
  }}
```

now from my lambda `files-metadata`  I am returning data like this :

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    output_files = [{"file":"name1"},{"file":"name2"},{"file":"name3"}]
    return json.dumps({'File_List':output_files})
```

but I am getting this error on step function which I am not able to figure out:

```
{
  "error": "States.Runtime",
  "cause": "Reference path \"$.File_List.Payload\" must point to array."
}
```

any lead to what I am doing wrong would be highly appreciated . thanks

and this is created my map state using python cdk .

```
 sfn_step_3 = tasks.LambdaInvoke(self, "fetch-sample",
                                        lambda_function=fetch_sample,
                                        output_path="$.Payload",
                                        integration_pattern=stepfunctions.IntegrationPattern.WAIT_FOR_TASK_TOKEN,
                                        payload=stepfunctions.TaskInput.from_object({
                                            "payload.$": "$",
                                            "execution_id.$": "$$.Execution.Id",
                                            "taskToken": stepfunctions.JsonPath.task_token
                                        })
                                        )
        self.map_state = stepfunctions.Map(
            self, "Map state",
            max_concurrency=10,
            items_path=stepfunctions.JsonPath.string_at("$.File_List"),
            result_path="$.Single.File",
        )
```